# React Navigation: How to invoke method inside main page from custom header in navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` :

```
const topSurvayorsNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    ActiveSurveyor: {
        screen: MomayezanScreen,
        params: { status: 1 },
    },
    DeActiveSurveyor: {
        screen: MomayezanScreen,
        params: { status: 0 },
    }
}, {
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 12
        },
        activeTintColor: Colors.darkGray
    }
});
```

I added this navigator into stack navigation :

```
const AuditMomayezanNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Dashboard: DashboardScreen,
    ListSurveyor: {
        screen: topSurvayorsNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            switch (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routeName"]) {
                case "ActiveSurveyor":
                    console.log("ActiveSurveyor")
                    return {
                        header: () => <CustomHeader
                            title='page1' 
                            onTermSubmit={() => searchApi(0)}
                            />
                    }

                case "DeActiveSurveyor":
                    console.log("DeActiveSurveyor")
                    return {
                        header: () => <CustomHeader
                            title='page2' 
                            onTermSubmit={() => searchApi(1)}
                            />
                    }
                default:
                    return { title: (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName }
            }
        }
    },
    Detail: SurveyorDetailsScreen,
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavOptions
});
```

As you can see i use custom header to stack navigation :

```
header: () => <CustomHeader
                  title='page1' 
                  onTermSubmit={() => searchApi(1)}
                  />
```

In custom view i have to send a method as `onTermSubmit` prop like searchApi with a parameter.How could i invoke searchApi(number) inside `MomayezanScreen` page from navigator?

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html
See the section of 
header interaction with component

Comment: As you can see in my code ,custom view in my code not blong to main page means MomayezanScreen.other problem is how could i send params and received it on MomayezanScreen ?